# can't find libz for a plone install on osx. brew tap homebrew/dups did not find it

Tags: plone, libz

THe plone installer complains that libz is missing on OSX Yosemite. brew can't find it, even after doing a "tap homebrew/dups".

Comment: Please expand you question, this is a very low quality question. Which version of Plone are you installing? What is the error traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your XCode command-line development environment:

```
sudo xcode-select -r
```

If that doesn't do it, reinstall XCode's command-line tools:

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Problems finding headers and libraries are common in upgraded XCode environments, but this should fix it.